# Marvosym in moderncv

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I am trying to use `marvosym` symobl for Email and telephone but with this code

```
    \documentclass[11pt,%                        % corpo del font: ci sono anche '10pt' e '12pt' 
               a4paper,%                     % carta A4
               sans,%                        % famiglia di font: c'è anche 'roman'
               ]{moderncv}                   % buona classe per CV

\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{fax}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{MARV}{fax}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     % codifica dei font:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % codifica di input:
\usepackage[german]{babel}                  % per scrivere in italiano
\usepackage{microtype}                       % microtipografia
\usepackage{lipsum}                          % genera testo fittizio
\moderncvstyle{classic}                      % tema di moderncv:
\moderncvcolor{blue}                         % colori di moderncv:
\nopagenumbers{}                            % decommenta per disabilitare la numerazione automatica delle pagine
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}            % imposta i margini
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}          % regola la larghezza della colonna con le date
\usepackage{mathtools}


\firstname{Ing. Nome}                  % nome
\familyname{Cognome}                        % cognome
\title{Curriculum vitae}                     % titolo del CV (opzionale: rimuovi la riga se non lo desideri)
\address{Via viaviavia 111}{12345 Città}     % indirizzo (opzionale)
\mobile{+12~345~67890123} 
\phone{+12~345~67890123}                      % telefono fisso (opzionale)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Email{danilo\_dandrea@hotmail.com} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Persönlich Angaben}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Geburtsort: S. Pietro Vernotico (IT)}{Geburtsdatum: 16. August 1974}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Ledig, keine Kinder, ortsungebunden}{Nationalität: Italienisch}

\end{document}
```

I get a compiler errorr: `Missing \begin{document}. \Email.` With `\email` instead of `\Email` it compiles but I don't get the envelope with the flash....

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

`\Email` is a symbol and not a command to store your address. You should do something like this to change the symbol:

```
\email{danilo\_dandrea@hotmail.com}
\renewcommand\emailsymbol{\Email}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your MWE if you are using the current version of `moderncv` (Please update, if not!).

The corrected MWE (I deleted some packages not neccessary for your problem here to make the example code shorter; at last Ulrike was faster, my English is not so good, it tooks me time):

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt,%     % corpo del font: ci sono anche '10pt' e '12pt' 
  a4paper,%               % carta A4
  sans,%                  % famiglia di font: c'è anche 'roman'
]{moderncv}               % buona classe per CV

\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{fax}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{MARV}{fax}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}   
\nopagenumbers{}                

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     % codifica dei font:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % codifica di input:
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                  % per scrivere in italiano
\usepackage{microtype}                       % microtipografia
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}            % imposta i margini


\firstname{Ing. Nome}                  % nome
\familyname{Cognome}                        % cognome
\title{Curriculum vitae}                     % titolo del CV (opzionale: rimuovi la riga se non lo desideri)
\address{Via viaviavia 111}{12345 Città}     % indirizzo (opzionale)
\mobile{+12~345~67890123} 
\phone{+12~345~67890123}                      % telefono fisso (opzionale)

\email{danilo\_dandrea@hotmail.com} 
\renewcommand\emailsymbol{\Email}


\begin{document}

\maketitle  %\makecvtitle

\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Geburtsort: S. Pietro Vernotico (IT)}{Geburtsdatum: 16. August 1974}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Ledig, keine Kinder, ortsungebunden}{Nationalität: Italienisch}

\end{document}
```

In line 12 I wrote the new call for `\moderncvtheme`.

In line 19 I changed `german` to `ngerman` (new german writing).

In line 31 is `\email` right.

In line 32 you see the changing of the symbol for the email.

In line 37 you should write `\maketitle`.

BTW: in line 39 is an `e` missing: `\section{Persönliche Angaben}` (I'm a German).